# ActiveModel::Error : Is there a way to get the error type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

What I want to achieve is to get the type of validation who failed. Was it blank ? Duplicate ? Length ?

```
class Film <; ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }
    validates :budget, :presence => true, :length => { :within => 1..10000000 }
end
```

I want to be able to do that

```
f = Film.create
f.errors.first.type = :presence
```

Or something like that. I want to do that to send the reason of the failure from my API to an API consumer (Mobile).

```
{
   "errors": [{
      "code": "film_empty_title",
      "reason": "empty"
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a post about how to do this on my blog:
https://pgord.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/quick-bit-reason-for-activerecord-rollback-in-the-rails-console/

In your case try this:

```
f = Film.create
f.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: In this case, I'll get a string which can change for many reasons on different versions.

Answer (score 0):

How about this backport from Rails 5: https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details

Answer (score -2):

use `.errors.on`

```
user = User.new
user.valid?
user.errors.on(:email)
  => "is not a valid email address.  Please check that you have typed or copied it correctly."
user.errors.on(:last_seen_at)
  => nil
```

Because this returns a string (truthy) or nil (falsy) you can use it in an if test like

```
if user.errors.on(:email)
  ...
```

In your case, wehere you want to create a json string of the errors, i thought that you might be able to simply do this:

```
json = {:errors => film.errors}.to_json
```

(note i'm using `film` rather than `f` as the variable name, it's much better to use descriptive names, and "f" is by convention the variable used to store a form when you're in the form block)

but for me, this gives me (using my user example)

```
"{\"errors\":[[\"password_confirmation\",\"is too short (minimum is 4 characters)\"], [\"first_name\",\"is too short (minimum is 1 characters)\"], [\"last_name\",\"is too short (minimum is 2 characters)\"], [\"login\",\"can't be blank\"], [\"password\",\"is too short (minimum is 4 characters)\"], [\"email\",\"is not a valid email address.  Please check that you have typed or copied it correctly.\"]]}"
```

which isn't quite what you need - it stores the errors in an array rather than a hash.

try this:

```
hash = {:errors => [{}]};film.errors.each{|f,m| hash[:errors][0][f] = m};hash
```

you can then do `hash.to_json` to get the actual response content.